# Suppress popup window in vbs on timeout of Windows Update Search

Tags: vbscript, windows-update

I have a vb-script which checks if there are updates pending. Sometimes windows search returns an error (for example 503) and an error popup is generated. Since I'm not familiar with vbs, I don't know where to start searching for a solution.

```
        Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
        Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()
        Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")
```

The problem occurs in line 3. It says:

```
Script: C:\path-to-my-script\my-script.vbs
Line:   3
Char:   1
Error:  0x80244022
Code:   80244022
Source: (null)
```

How can I either prevent the popup from being generated or get a handle to it and close it immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 0x80244022 means that the update server HTTP service became temporarily unavailable (for whatever reason). See [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941) for a list of connectivity-related error codes.

To handle this error put it between an `On Error Resume Next` and an `On Error Goto 0` statement:

```
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

On Error Resume Next
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")
If Err Then
  'add logging routine here
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
On Error Goto 0

'more code here
```

Note that the above will indiscriminately terminate the script on any error that occurs when calling the `Search` method. If you want to handle different errors in different ways, you could for instance put a `Select` statement inside the conditional:

```
If Err Then
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case &h80244022
      'quit immediately
      WScript.Quit 1
    Case &h8009033F
      'wait some time and retry
      WScript.Sleep 900000
      Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search(...)
    Case &h...
      'just log a message and continue
      ...
  End Select
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew what the reason for the error was, but since I never programmed vbscript myself, I didn't know how to handle it or where to start searching. Thanks a lot for both pointers, I will proceed from there.